# Using Pandas to copy filtered rows to new sheet, is there a way to append the old row# to the last cell for each copied row?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, xlsx

I'm trying to filter a large sheet through Python, I read the .xlsx into a new dataframe, filter rows that have a specific value, then output each matching row into a new dataframe.

However, my issue is I would like to append a new column that simply contains the "old" row numbers from the origin sheet. I'm not really sure how to accomplish this efficiently.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(path, sheet_name='Sheet 1')

matching_term_list = ['TRUE', 'FALSE']
column_name = 'True/False/NA'

df_filtered_command = df[df[col_name_type].isin(matching_term_list)]
df_filtered_command.columns = column_headers
df_filtered_command.head()

with pd.ExcelWriter('new_sheet.xlsx') as writer:
    df_filtered_command.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Command", index=False)
```

Comment: Goes using `index=True` get you what you want?

Comment: @PaulH It adds some kind of list to the the new sheets (The index), but it overwrites an existing column and the numbers don't seem to correlate to the sheet I copied them from. Could you expand a bit more on how I could use this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you filter the dataframe, you can then reset the index and not drop the old one, which will add a new column "index".  I the renamed it to be "Old Index":

```
df_filtered_command = df[df[col_name_type].isin(matching_term_list)].reset_index(drop=False).rename(columns={"index": "Old Index"})
```

If this is out by 1 or so for the actual Excel row (because of a header, etc.), you can then use:

```
df_filtered_command["Old Index"] += 1
```

Comment: That's awesome. I do have headers which I assign to the new sheets later in my code. The index doesn't seem to get labeled on the sheet itself however, and it always seems to start at 0 (even though the first "cell" of the original sheet that gets copied is 2

Comment: So you can add 2 in the second bit of code, which should solve that problem (as 0 becomes 2, 97 becomes 99, etc.).